# Ajax Database Livesearch Undefined Index

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

EDIT: NVM fixed it completely. Woot woot.

---

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the error "undefined index: cfname keeps appearing in the following code.

This is the search.php which runs the live search

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[

function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
{ 
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
//]]>
</script>
<form>
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Customer search:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="15" onKeyUp="showResult(this.value)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>
```

And this is the html page

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$hint="";
$q=$_GET["q"];
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cfname LIKE '%$q%'");
while($serresult=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$hint='<div><input type="submit" name="cid[]" value="'.$serresult['cfname'].'" /></div>';
}
}


// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values

if ($hint=="")
{
$response="no suggestion";
}
else
{
$response=$hint;
}
//output the response
echo $response;
```

What the live search is supposed to do is to display the customer names (cfname) as you type in the customer search box. As I typed in correct keys, it tells my that cfname is an undefined index.

Now I don't know if this is your usual undefined index error because when I change * in the $res query to cfname, it works perfectly but it only displays one search, whereas if I use * I can see that it displays more than one available search albeit an error.

So like, the names are Bob Smith and Jon Smith. If I use this original code and type in Smith, two possible searches appear but with the undefined index error. If I change * to cfname, only one of them appears as possible searches.

I'm not sure anymore what error I'm having and how I could fix it. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($serresult)` - What does that output?

Comment: Have you tried using `while($serresult=mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_BOTH))`

Comment: @kyra; var_dump displays all information in array format, with still the error of undefined index. Changing * to cfname meanwhile fixes the undefined index error but still displays the info in array. 

@saravanan: Tried, even combining with Kyra's suggestion. Didn't work.